# Google App Engine: is_current_user_admin how can I tell if the admin is a owner, developer or viewer?

Tags: google-app-engine

In appengine, you can give different privileges to users:

```
owner, developer or viewer.
```

I'd like to be able to query that information from the Python API.

Is this possible now? If not, is it on the road map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not currently possible, no - the Users API will only return if the user is an admin or not. You should check if there's a feature request filed, and file one if there isn't.

Comment: Hi Nick,  Thanks for the tip.  As you suggested, I checked and it already is a feature request.  For those that would like to star it, see http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4897

Comment: @RalphYozzo I think you should mark this answer as a correct one, since Nick is actually working for Google App Engine and it couldn't be more accurate ;)

Comment: @Lipis Thanks so much for pointing that out.  I did not know about the check mark feature.  And you are correct.  Nick Johnson is GREAT!